# Concatenar uma @string e um texto em XML

Tags: android, android-xml

Tenho uma string chamada "key" e queria adicionar o números sequênciais ao lado dela em alguns textviews

, mas não sei como concatenar em XML.
Por exemplo:

```
android:text="@string/key" + "1"
android:text="@string/key" + "2"
android:text="@string/key" + "3"
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Isso não é possível fazer no XML, apenas no Java/Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dessa forma não é possível.

Uma abordagem possível é criar uma classe que herde da *view* que pretende usar e dar-lhe essa capacidade.

Comece por declarar um atributo a ser usado no *xml*. Ele servirá para receber o valor a concatenar ao valor atribuído a `android:text`.

Na pasta ***/res/values*** crie, caso não exista, um arquivo chamado *attrs.xml*, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ConcatenateTextView">
        <attr name="concatenate" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Caso o arquivo já exista inclua nele apenas

```
<declare-styleable name="ConcatenateTextView">
    <attr name="concatenate" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

A View a herdar terá de ser uma que tenha o atributo `android:text`, qualquer uma que, directa um indirectamente, herde de TextView.

Exemplo para TextView:

**ConcatenateTextView.java**

```
public class ConcatenateTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    public ConcatenateTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ConcatenateTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        handleCustomAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    public ConcatenateTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        handleCustomAttributes(context, attrs);
    }

    private void handleCustomAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.ConcatenateTextView,
                0, 0);

        String concatenateText = a.getString(R.styleable.ConcatenateTextView_concatenate);
        if(concatenateText != null){
            setText(getText() + concatenateText);
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
<o.seu.name.space.ConcatenateTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/key"
    app:concatenate="1"/>
```